# Histograms with different scales in one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two datasets whose each observation represents a travel time of a vehicle from one place to another in a given network.

I am trying to plot a histogram for each dataset in the same plot. However, the result is not that readable as the standard deviation of one dataset is too high:

[image]

Any thoughts on how I could improve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Plot the second one on `twinx()`?

Comment: I have tried that out. However, in that case, the readability does not look good.